# Vue project missing style in production

Tags: css, docker, nginx, vue.js, proxy

When I run my *docker image* and proxy the requests with *nginx* I run into issues with the styling.

I see all the html-tags, I find the css and js files when I look at the *network* tab in the browser, the css looks correct to me, **BUT** there is **no styling applied**. Basically, all html-tags looks generic and booring.

When I develop I have no issues with the styling, I also see styling when I just run *npm run build*.

The project is built using [vue/cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), but I have also tried other templates with earlier versions of webpack resulting in the same issue.

In **.vue** files I use the *single-file-component* structure and use **lang="scss"**.

My *nginx.conf* looks like this:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

stream...

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name vue-node;

        gzip                on;
        gzip_proxied        any;
        gzip_http_version   1.1;
        gzip_comp_level     5;
        gzip_min_length     256;
        gzip_vary           on;
        gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

        root /opt/vue-node/dist;
        index index.html;

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://vuenode:8000;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
        }
        location @rewrites {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
        }
    }
}
```

My *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM node:9-stretch

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    vim \
    nginx

COPY . /opt/vue-node/
WORKDIR /opt/vue-node/

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD packaging/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN npm install -g npm \
 && npm install -g @vue/cli \
 && npm install \
 && npm run build

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
EXPOSE 80
```

I set NODE_ENV=production in my docker-compose.yml.

Everything else is pretty much as the *vue/cli* set it up.

Ask me for more information and I will provide it.
I appreciate any and all help I can get!

Comment: Do you use scoped styles? If so, check if css selector matches data attribute in HTML. Maybe they are out-of-sync. Example: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Comment: The css look correct to me and the html tag has the same info in the tag:
css: ".scoped-class[data-v-xxx]{...}"
inspected html: "<div data-v-xxx/>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
The issue was my ignorance about Nginx.

When I **overwrite** the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** some configurations were lost from the default nginx config that was neccessary. Im not sure what settings that was, but I read that the **Best Practice** is to add you custom proxy locations in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/** which will be imported by the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file by default. I ended up with:

Dockerfile:

```
COPY packaging/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY packaging/mongo.conf /etc/nginx/streams/available/mongo
```

default.conf:

```
# no stream module..

server {
# a simple server module..
}
```

mongo.conf:

```
stream {
# the stream module, proxy to mongodb..
}
```